# Como inserir um marcador que cresça numericamente em um dataframe no R?

Tags: r, contador

Tenho um dataframe com uma coluna e um determinado número de linhas que varia. No que estou trabalhando são 17. Em cada linha há uma expressão diferente, mais ou menos parecida com "ID 123456, cor = azul".

Gostaria que fosse acrescentada a cada uma das linhas uma palavra que me ajude a identificar cada uma dessas linhas. Eu precisaria de algo do tipo cod1, cod2, cod3 etc. Acontece que como disse antes, a quantidade de linhas muda regularmente. Então, neste caso são 17 linhas, mas podem ser mais ou menos. Portanto, precisaria que a palavra que vai identificar cada uma dessas linhas se adeque à quantidade de linhas.

Comment: A pergunta está um pouco genérica demais. Edite a pergunta, colocando o data frame de 17 linhas original. Utilize o output do comando dput(dataframe) para isto. Também coloque o resultado esperado deste contador, para que entendamos o teu objetivo.

Comment: Olá, @MarcusNunes, agradeço a dica, sou iniciante nisso tudo. Após boa pesquisa, acabei conseguindo evoluir nessa questão, mas já surgiu outra, no entanto, não sei como proceder, pois é a primeira vez que utilizo o forum - criando uma pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você pode fazer um for assim:

```
for(j in 1:dim(seu dataframe)[1]){
    seu dataframe[j,]$posicao <- paste0("cod",j)
    j=j+1
  }
```

essa função vai concatenar a palavra cod com o contador... vai ficar cod1 na primeira linha, cod2 na segunda e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Deu certo!